# Windows - Register to Notification when Hard Drives get plugged in/removed

Tags: .net, windows, networking, hard-drive

does anyone here know if it is possible to receive notifications in Windows when a User plugs in a hard drive / removes one ? I ask this because I am doing a job for a big media company which runs solely on Windows machines. because their video files are really really huge they somehow adopted a system where they continuously swap in and out hard drives into transcoder machines. My job is now to somehow monitor and manage this chaos.

What I need is a notification that whenever a user shoves a hard drive into one of the servers and one when he removes a hard drive. Is this possible? I am happy with C/C++/C# answers. Doesn't matter.

Thanks, 
Markus

Addendum: I just had the idea to mabe poll System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives every n seconds. Has anyone experience with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect insertion of media into a drive using windows messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420131/detect-insertion-of-media-into-a-drive-using-windows-messages) or [How do I get a notification when user creates a mount point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226758/how-do-i-get-a-notification-when-user-creates-a-mount-point)

Comment: thanks. your first link brought me here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx will check out!